# Test discovery drops Python namespaces from relative imports?

Tags: python, namespaces, python-unittest

I encountered a strange issue with unit tests in a namespaced package. [Here's an example I built on GitHub](https://github.com/kojiromike/example-python-package/tree/coverage-ignores-tests). Here's the basic structure:

```
$ tree -P '*.py' src 
src
└── namespace
    └── testcase
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── a.py
        ├── sub
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   └── b.py
        └── tests
            ├── __init__.py
            └── test_imports.py

4 directories, 6 files
```

I would expect that relative imports within a namespaced package would maintain the namespace. Normally, that seems to be true:

```
$ cat src/namespace/testcase/a.py 
print(__name__)
$ cat src/namespace/testcase/sub/b.py 
print(__name__)

from ..a import *
$ python -c 'from namespace.testcase.sub import b'
namespace.testcase.sub.b
namespace.testcase.a
```

But if I involve a test, I get a surprise:

```
$ cat src/namespace/testcase/tests/test_imports.py 
from namespace.testcase import a
from ..sub import b
$ python -m unittest discover src/namespace/
namespace.testcase.a
testcase.sub.b
testcase.a

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

The code in `src/namespace/testcase/a.py` is getting run twice! In my case, this caused a singleton I had stubbed to be re-initialized as a real object, subsequently causing test failures.

Is this expected behavior? What is the correct usage here? Should I always avoid relative imports (and have to do global search-and-replace if my company decides to rename something?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem: Overlapping `sys.path` entries

The duplicate imports with different module names happen when you have overlapping `sys.path` entries: that is, when `sys.path` contains both a parent and child directory as separate entries. This situation is almost always an error: it will make Python see the child directory as a separate, unrelated root for imports, which leads surprising behaviour.

In your example:

```console
$ python -m unittest discover src/namespace/
namespace.testcase.a
testcase.sub.b
testcase.a
```

This means that both `src` and `src/namespace` ended up in `sys.path`, so that:

- **namespace.testcase.a** was imported relative to `src`
- **testcase.sub.b** and **testcase.a** were imported relative to `src/namespace`

#### Why?

In this case, the overlapping `sys.path` entries happen because `unittest discover` is trying to be helpful: it defaults to assuming that the start directory for test discovery is also the top-level directory that your imports are relative to, and it will insert that top-level directory into `sys.path` if it's not already there, as a convenience. (…not so convenient, it turns out. ️)

### Solution: Explicitly specify the correct top-level directory

You can explicitly specify the correct top-level directory with `-t` (`--top-level-directory`):

```console
python -m unittest discover -t src -s src/namespace/
```

This will work as before, but won't treat `src/namespace` as a top-level directory to insert into `sys.path`.

**Side note:** The `-s` option prefix for `src/namespace/` was implicit in the previous example: the above just makes it explicit.
(`unittest discover` has weird positional argument handling: it treats its first three positional arguments as values for `-s`, `-p`, and `-t`, in that order.)

### Details

The code responsible for this lives in [unittest/loader.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.1/Lib/unittest/loader.py#L274-L286):

```python
class TestLoader(object):

    def discover(self, start_dir, pattern='test*.py', top_level_dir=None):

        ...

        if top_level_dir is None:
            set_implicit_top = True
            top_level_dir = start_dir

        top_level_dir = os.path.abspath(top_level_dir)

        if not top_level_dir in sys.path:
            # all test modules must be importable from the top level directory
            # should we *unconditionally* put the start directory in first
            # in sys.path to minimise likelihood of conflicts between installed
            # modules and development versions?
            sys.path.insert(0, top_level_dir)

        ...
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks for linking to the loader.py. Now I also understand why my first attempts to use the dotted module name failed. It seems to me the namespace-module handling in loader.py is incomplete, since [`_get_directory_containing_module`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.1/Lib/unittest/loader.py#L340) can't handle it if the module given it is a namespace one. But, if I monkeypatch it, test discovery works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly why `unittest` wouldn't respect your `setup.py`, but indeed often it does not (maybe a bug, or a difficulty in doing so for the implementers). Or perhaps `unittest` is by design very "low level" and does not come with any bells or whistles you'd expect from something like [pytest](https://pypi.org/project/pytest/).

What you need to do is help `unittest` out and tell it where your package starts, use the `--top-level-directory` option for that (or `-t` for short).

This should work as you expect:

```
python -m unittest discover -t src/ src/namespace/
```

The issue is that you probably have something like this in your `setup.py`:

```
    package_dir={"": "src"},
```

And unfortunately `unittest` is not "smart enough" to figure that out.

This is one example detail why I strongly prefer [pytest](https://pypi.org/project/pytest/) to std-lib's `unittest` :)

`pytest` will go to greater lengths to "do the right thing", while not forcing you to be verbose in your test run invocation (for example: it auto-discovers recursively by default etc).

If you want to learn more about how `unittest` imports things, you can add this line to your `a.py` file:

```
assert __package__ == "namespace.testcase"
```

Then, run your test without the `-t src/` as you originally did -> you will see exactly where `unittest` is crashing. If you open that code, you will see that all it does is try to simply `__import__(name)`, where `name` is simply the thing it just found that could look like a test.

Tests are usually NOT in a package, a more strict project layout would be like:

```
src/namespace/ # -> your project or lib
tests/         # -> your tests
```

The above is "more strict" because it makes it harder to confuse your tests with your actual shipped code (ie: no oopsie `import ..tests.foo` from the actual code).

Now, given this, a lot of testing tools like `unittest` and `pytest`, will kind of assume that your tests don't really have a package, so they will import them as-if the package doesn't matter at all...

Ie: they won't necessarily try and import `test_foo.py` as-if it was under your main top-level name.

So, in theory you should (from my experience writing tests):

- use relative imports from within your actual code only (ie: any non-test submodule)
- use full absolute import from the tests (that simplifies quite a few things for testing tools + it allows to treat your code "less intimately" from the tests -> kinda forces you to `import` stuff from your `namespace` project like any other user would do)

Hope that helps. I don't have handy links to docs on this (and maybe it would be worth a good book). But consider this: if you write this from your test:

```
from ..sub import b
```

You are taking shortcuts a user of your library cannot do. Anyone who would `pip install namespace` for example would have to import `b` with an absolute import:

```
from namespace.sub import b
```

It is helpful I find to isolate tests from the code itself. I know many projects do just add a `tests/` subfolder to their main code tree, but I do find that odd, since that ships the tests together with the published package, and one could technically import the tests just like the rest of the code... for example:

```
from namespace.testcase.tests import test_imports
```

An example of `tests/` outside the main code tree is the [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests) package.

Followed the code, as this got me curious.

`unittest discover` looks for test cases, it finds `testcase/` which looks like a test folder to it.
So it simply does a "standalone" (ie: regardless of any "top-level" context) `import testcase`.

Then your test does this (all of these imports are simply cached in `sys.modules`, by name):

- `from namespace.testcase import a`, which triggers the import of `a` as a submodule of `namespace.testcase` as expected
- but then it calls `from ..sub import b`, now in unittest's context, this expands to `testcase.sub.b`, which then leads to the confusion.

Comment: For what it's worth, pytest discovery behaved the same. As did django-admin test on the original project I discovered this behavior in.

Comment: I just tried in `pytest` and couldn't reproduce your described case (no matter how it is invoked: just `pytest`, or `pytest src` or `pytest src/namespace/` etc...). You can add this line to `a.py`, it will trigger an exception as soon as a bad import occurs:
`assert __package__ == "namespace.testcase"`. I wasn't able to trigger that exception in `pytest`, but observed it in `unittest` (also tried with `pytest --capture-no`, and I do see your expected output)

Comment: Oops, that is `pytest --capture=no` (typo in prev comment...).

Comment: Also, if you do simply this: `python -m unittest discover src/`, you shouldn't run into this problem either. I did notice that you didn't have a `__init__.py` file in `src/namespace/`, I assumed that it was simply forgotten in the `tree` output in your question. If not, you do need to mark `src/namespace/` as a python module (even if it is a bona-fide namespace - in which case an empty `__init__.py` won't do, but that's a whole other question)

Comment: Edited answer with a general note. I must admit I tend not to do have my `tests/` folder inside the main code tree, so perhaps this is exposing a particular edge case in `unittests` from that practice

Comment: Got me curious, so I followed the code :)
Editing my question to include that explanation

Comment: I edited my question to include a link to an example testcase I built on GitHub.